# How to say when you have a "lock" or "block" to do something (like talk in public)?

Tags: expressions

Is it correct (or the best way to say) the expression `I have a "lock" or "block"`, when talking about a emotional obstacle to start something (like a public presentation)?

Comment: There are a number of words, but it is not clear exactly what meaning you are reaching for, or the context. Please expand your question to provide more detail on these in order to get the best responses.

Comment: I'd say you have "a mental block" about that activity.  (Though fear of public speaking is a well-known and distinct psychological fear.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's erroneously conflating *[mental] **block*** with "lock".

Comment: Maybe you "freeze up"?

Comment: Similar as *mental block* or *emotional blockage*: "psychological block".

Comment: You can have a lock on something you can block about something.  I don't see why the OP's error requires his question be closed.

Comment: The technical term for fear of public speaking is "glossophobia", though in the vernacular it is generally grouped in with "stage fright".

Comment: @FumbleFingers wouldn't be better correcting than closing?

Comment: Definition 26 for [**block**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/block) *- an obstruction or stoppage in mental processes or speech, especially when related to stress, emotional conflict, etc.* Not that many native speakers would be likely to use *I had a block* to mean they ***froze*** (and were unable to  speak at a public presentation), but if they *did* it would probably mean they ***couldn't think*** of what to say (where *to freeze* would probably mean they ***couldn't speak*** (perhaps being intimidated by the occasion). But what exactly are you asking that's not in the dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a *block*.  Examples: *writer's block*.

You could *lock onto a **topic***.  In Star Trek, they would "lock onto So-and-So's coordinates in preparation for beaming the person up or down.

Answer (score -1):

Personally I think I would go with *phobia*

> I have a *phobia* that prevents me from speaking in public.

or as mentioned in one of the comments *mental block* is also a good fit.

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: I don't feel strongly enough to downvote, but I'll explain that I'm not upvoting this one because *phobia* is longer term than *block*.  Also, the way one experiences the two things is quite different.

Comment: didn't realize letters were at a premium

Comment: I have to apologize -- I think I must have been sleepy when I wrote my comment.  I meant *stronger*, not *longer*.